# Возможно ли анимировать высоту элемента?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь в приложении сделать появление view'шки с ошибкой, как в Android 5.0.

[image]

Живой пример можно найти в приложении Gmail. Не знаю, как конкретно там, но я пытался сделать так:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFragmentError"
        style="@style/fragmentErrorStyle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainFragmentErrorButton"
            style="@style/fragmentErrorButtonStyle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainFragmentErrorText"
            style="@style/fragmentErrorTextStyle"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mainFragmentErrorButton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mainFragmentGridView"
        style="@style/mainFragmentGridViewStyle"
        android:layout_above="@id/mainFragmentError" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Для появления ошибки я использовал анимацию:

```
<translate
    android:duration="@string/anim_normalSpeed"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

а в java коде

```
mainFragmentError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mainFragmentError.startAnimation(showErrorAnimation);
```

Таким образом сначала резервируется место под mainFragmentError, потом содержимое плывет снизу вверх. Но смотрится это не совсем приятно, ибо перед анимацией видна пустая область. Потому возник вопрос, а возможно ли адекватно анимировать появление view'шки mainFragmentError, чтобы плавно увеличивать ее высоту? (Добавлять анимацию  пробовал, та же песня.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться вот [этой библиотекой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/243363/) для анимаций.

А вообще это называется SnackBar, и есть уже [готовые реализации](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar).

Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, посмотрите на [сайте](http://android-libs.com/) или в [приложении](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos) готовые библиотеки.
В приложении можно сразу же посмотреть реализацию в действии.

Comment: Вот только чушь это, даже в живом примере использования библиотеки идет простое перекрытие snackbar'ом содержимого (ListView, ScrollView, хз что из этого), а эта ситуация как раз описана в документации по Material Design'у, и там ясно написано: don't (да и догадаться можно без проблем, что это совсем убого смотрится).

Comment: Если бы вы посмотрели внимательно, то в том же gmail идет такое же перекрытие содержимого, единственное, что там происходит при появлении, то это поднятие FloatingButton вместе со SnackBar.